# Why I am having this CV::Resize Error in this piece of code?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have split my image data in train, test and validation set. Now, I want to check images in one of these folders. As an output, I am Expecting images of particular height and width from orig_train and forg_val randomly. Instead, I am getting this error.

```
def visualize_sample_signature():
    '''Function to randomly select a signature from train set and
    print two genuine copies and one forged copy'''
    img_h, img_w = 200, 500

    fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize = (10, 10))
    k = np.random.randint(len(orig_train))
    orig_img_names = random.sample(orig_train[k], 2)
    forg_img_name = random.sample(forg_val[k], 1)
    orig_img1 = cv2.imread(orig_img_names[0], 0)
    orig_img2 = cv2.imread(orig_img_names[1], 0)
    forg_img = cv2.imread(forg_img_name[0], 0)
    orig_img1 = cv2.resize(orig_img1, (img_w, img_h))
    orig_img2 = cv2.resize(orig_img2, (img_w, img_h))
    forg_img = cv2.resize(forg_img, (img_w, img_h))

visualize_sample_signature()
```

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-8ca6484a3a89> in <module>
----> 1 visualize_sample_signature()

<ipython-input-136-1f5de68e5af9> in visualize_sample_signature()
      9     orig_img2 = cv2.imread(orig_img_names[1], 0)
     10     forg_img = cv2.imread(forg_img_name[0], 0)
---> 11     orig_img1 = cv2.resize(orig_img1, (img_w, img_h))
     12     orig_img2 = cv2.resize(orig_img2, (img_w, img_h))
     13     forg_img = cv2.resize(forg_img, (img_w, img_h))

error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare img_w and img_h as globals within the function that uses them.

Comment: Did it. But got the same error again. What is the other possible reason?

Comment: Please update the code in the question to reflect the change

Comment: Done. But still Error is not gone. What should I try more?

Comment: Thank you so much. My error resolved. My path was incorrect.